# RHEL 8 - Module Streams

Tags: rhel8

In my RHEL 8 box, I've just created local repos (BaseOS & AppStream) based on the RHEL 8 ISO and I can successfully install packages.
However, when I'm trying to list modules or some specific module I get nothing :

```
   [root@master yum.repos.d]# dnf module list
   Local_AppStream                                                                                                        
   Local_BaseOS           


   [root@master yum.repos.d]# dnf module list  php
   Last metadata expiration check: 0:04:17 ago on Tue 07 Apr 2020 10:38:23 AM EDT.
   Error: No matching Modules to list
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was fixed , misconfigured repos. Thanks